# Split a string in Java if it contains digit - but include digit in result?

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to split a string using Java if it contains a digit or underscore - but I want to include the digit in the result - is this possible?

Eg.

"Linux_version"
"Linux3.1.2.x"

I want to split strings like these to get either "version" if it contains an underscore, or the digits to the end of the string if it contains a digit - e.g. from the second string above - I want "3.1.2.x"

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expectedString = yourString.replaceAll("^[^_0-9]+_?","");
```

If you just want to remove `Linux` or `Linux_`, try this:

```
expectedString = yourString.replaceAll("(?i)^linux_?","")
```

Comment: +1 I like yours better :)  (but mine *is* harder to read :D )

Comment: Great, would anyone be able to explain what "^[^_0-9]+?", "" does. Think it says for lines not starting with one or more _ or 0-9, replace with "" - but what does the ? mean

Comment: @Rory: It(`?`) matches the previous character(here,`_`) zero or one time. Pattern like `X+?` matches X one or more times but the difference is that it is a `reluctant` modifier.

Comment: Thanks prince - I've posted another regex question similar to this if you want to have a look at it :-) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929236/complicated-regex-is-this-possible

Answer (score 1):

This regex replace will do it:

```
input.replaceAll("^.*?((?<=_)|(?=\\d))", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "Linux_version";
//String input = "Linux3.1.2.x";
String result = null;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(.*)|(\\d.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher();
if (m.find()){
  if (m.group(1) != null){
    result = m.group(1); //"version"
  } else if (m.group(2) != null){
    result = m.group(2); //"3.1.2.x"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with java code but I think you can use the following regex pattern;

(_|[0-9])+[.a-zA-Z0-9]+