# Complicated regex - is this possible?

Tags: java, regex

For the following strings, I am trying to extract 'mainline' if the string contains mainline, or the number at the end if it doesnt contain mainline. I am using Java.

Eg, for the following strings I want just the numbers at the end

```
Solaris10NBngp-bwm1.1.X     // want 1.1.x
Solaris10NBbytel2.0.0.0x    // want 2.0.0.0x
Solaris10NBbwm1.2.X         // want 1.2.X
Solaris10NBoam_bwm1.4.0.X   // want 1.4.0X
Solaris10NBoam1.7.X         // want 1.7.X
```

Mainline examples:

```
Solaris10NBngp-bwm_mainline // want mainline
LinuxNBdaypass_mainline     // want mainline
LinuxNBngp_mainline         // want mainline
```

Is this possible using regex, and if so, anybody know how to do it? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Solaris10NBngp-bwm1.1.X     // want 1.1.x 
Solaris10NBbytel2.0.0.0x    // want 2.0.0.0x 
Solaris10NBbwm1.2.X         // want 1.2.X 
Solaris10NBoam_bwm1.4.0.X   // want 1.4.0X 
Solaris10NBoam1.7.X         // want 1.7.X
```

For the above inputs,

```
expectedString = yourString.replaceAll("[^.]+(\\d+\\.)","$1");
```

Comment: Thanks , this did the trick, im just using an if statement to check for mainline, and this in the else clause for strings that don't contain mainline - many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings always start with `Solaris10NB`, try this expression: `Solaris10NB[\w\-]+(\d.*)`.

Then extract the first group using `Matcher#group(1)`.

Comment: Look again at the OP's first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression

```
([0-9.]+x) +.*$
```

*NB Assuming the comments are a part of the string*

Otherwise

```
[0-9.]+x)$
```

Comment: First expression matches with "...x ", second with "...x". It doesn't look like what is needed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

See if this expression works

```
(\d\.)+\d?X$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/(mainline)$|(\d+\..*)\s*/
```

If it finds `mainline` at the string end then `$1` variable will contain the value `mainline`. If it finds a version number then `$2` variable will be populated the `$1` will be null/empty.